# Can I dynamically configure and run JavaExec task in Gradle or is there any alternative to it?

Tags: java, gradle, exec

I have problem with my task and its configuration phase. I don't want to configure JavaExec task every time I build, because even if run other tasks I need to supply some parameters with -P which are required in configuration phase of my JavaExec task.

Is there a way to run java program from jar in some task, supplying arguments during execution of task (and not in configuration phase)?

Comment: You can always configure this task with *if* logic - checking if required `-P` params were passed. If no, `warn` to console and don't configure the task.

Comment: Can you able to use environment variables?

Comment: It's bit more complicated in fact. I'm loading properties files basing on those parameters (user / enviorment specific configs) and I would have to put loading in configuration phase too. I've tried that and it was becoming very problematic very quickly.

Comment: you could probably move the reading of the properties file into the doFirst block of the javaexec task then

Comment: yeah, but that would be really not elegant... I have  "loadProperties" task for that and some tasks will depend on it. I don't want to duplicate and complicate my code (by creating needlessly long configurations for tasks).